# 10.8.4 pretending updates don't exist

Tags: macos

I just upgraded to 10.8.4; I had to do this by downloading the update .dmg from Apple as my computer has decided on its own to opt-out of software updates. Both the App Store and softwareupdate report that there are no updates available even though I know full well that there is a Java update and iTunes is not the latest version. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a non admin user account? Then available system updates and updates for Apple software will not show in the Mac App Store when invoking Software Update. What you can do is the following: Open Mac App Store, click on „Updates“ and then press cmd-R. A dialogue will open asking for your admin name and password. Then all available updates for OS X and Apple software will be listed.

Comment: Sadly, no, I'm using an admin account. The softwareupdate command line tool I tried even requires sudo.